# i am having troubles with nusoap api with php ??how can i get it working with recent php version?

Tags: web-services, nusoap

I am trying to use `nusoap` api for php core web applicaton. Problems with `nusoap` client while worked with soap client `.Nusoap` doesn't work at all ..and furthermore i am not finding any relevent help for the same .Using `php 5.4.3` and `nusoap 0.9.5` ...

```
require_once '../lib/nusoap.php';
require_once '../my-methods/functions.php';

$wsdl = "index.php?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$val = $client->GetWalk(14);
var_dump($val);
$soap = new nusoap_client($wsdl);
$soapaction =  "../check_soap.php";
$err = $soap->getError();
var_dump($err);
$soap->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$res = $soap->call('GetWalk',15,$wsdl,$soapaction);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: you are doing var_dump at 3 places , what output you are getting? Paste output of your script that you are getting in browser. So that we all can see what is happening, and some one will then be able to solve your problem.

Comment: object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'WalkId' => int 14
  public 'WalkTitle' => string 'Title of my long walk' (length=21)
  public 'WalkDate' => string '2013-04-22' (length=10)
  public 'WalkDescription' => string 'Really long walk description' (length=28)

boolean false

boolean false